# Does anyone know what "ValueError: Error when checking input:" keras error mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I am sort of a noob when it comes to keras ad tensorflow, so I could really use some help to try and figure out this issue that I am having with my code.  I am trying to run an auto encoder program.  However, when I try to run the program, I get an error along the lines of: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 256, 256, 3).  I am pretty sure that the program is having trouble pulling images from my database that I made, in a directory called train.  I am ruining this code on a raspberry pi, and this is my code:

```
 from keras.layers import Input, Dense
 from keras.models import Model
 import numpy as np
 from PIL import Image 
 from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 image = Image.open('/home/pi/Downloads/neural-network- 
 master/data/train/class_a/test(2chunk0.wav).png.jpg')
 encoding_dim = 28
 input_img = Input(shape=(65536,))
 encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_img)
 decoded = Dense(65536, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)
 autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
 encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)
 encoded_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
 decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
 decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))
 autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
 train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
 train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
     directory=r"/home/pi/Downloads/neural-network-master/data/train",
     batch_size=32,
     class_mode="categorical",
     shuffle=True,
     seed=42
 )
 autoencoder.fit_generator(train_generator,
            epochs=2,
            steps_per_epoch=256,
            shuffle=True)
 encoded_img = encoder.predict(np.array(image))
 print (encoded_img)
 decoded_img = decoder.predict(encoded_img)
 plt.imshow(decoded_img)
 plt.imshow(image)
```

The exact error that I keep getting is this:

```
 ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 2 
 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 256, 256, 3)
```

Once again, I believe that this is a problem with the program not liking the way I have formatted the directories containing the training data.  I have a directory called class_a inside of my train directory, and two more directories inside of class_a called class_1 and class_2, and the data inside of these folders.  I could be wrong about this being the problem, but any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:
so i changed the line that looks like this:
     input_img = Input(shape=(65536,))
to this:
     input_img = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3,))
and that seemed to fix part of the problem, but now when I run the code, I get this error:

```
 ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (262, 1)
```

once again, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your input need to be resized **(65536)** instead of  **(256, 256, 3)**

Answer (score 0):

This error happend when you try to fit data with a different shape as the one expected by the model.
Here you define an expected input of shape (65536,) and you try to fit data with a shape of (256, 256, 3) to it.

So you need to reshape your inputs to match the one expected by the model.

Try this :

```
input_img = Input(shape=(256*256*3,))
```

and reshape your input data to a single vector of same shape (nb_batch, 256*256*3)

Comment: so I edited my code to make the line:                                                                 
       input_img = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3,)), but now I get the error: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 1)
Exception ignored in: <function WeakValueDictionary.__init__.<locals>.remove at 0x7546eed0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/weakref.py", line 117, in remove
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable